# Got a pay cut for a sporadic project

Tags: communication, salary, freelancing

My friend is a freelancer, he has been working for over a year with another three freelancers for a company.

Today he and the other freelancers were notified by email that they will be getting a 40% paycut in a specific project. The justification for the paycut was along the lines of: "This project is not a priority, and you don't need to spend much time on it. It's OK if your tasks are not perfect."

The thing is that my friend and the other freelancers receive tasks for this project only once or twice a month so it's not that big of a deal for him, though enough to be concerned.

While it's a little paycut I cannot help but wonder if this is just the beginning considering that it was non-negotiable.

For now I advised him to contact the other freelancers to see if any of them has ever experienced this kind of paycut and how it was resolved in the end.
Also I told him to suggest to the other freelances (if nobody knows what to do) working 40% less on tasks of this specific project, and if they all agree go this course of action together.

This is what I would do but I'd like to know if anybody here has ever experienced this situation and what would be the wisest thing to do.

Edit: Neither he nor the other freelances have a contract.

Edit 2: Freelancers in his industry are unipersonal-companies, they create invoices for their work, and pay their taxes.

Comment: Obligatory question: What does your friends contract say about pay rates?

Comment: You may get more direct experience in your answers if you go to https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PeterM Neither he nor the other freelances have a contract. I added this to my question right now.

Comment: @Myles maybe, but I thought that asking it here would be better because the course of action I proposed involved communication with colleges.

Comment: There is no such thing as doing work, getting paid and not having a contract. What country are you in?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul this is a thing in a competitive freelance world. My friend is from Europe and he is changed countries (inside Europe) already twice while working for this company.

Comment: @freelance-friend No, it's not a thing, it especially is not a thing in Europe. Or at least it's not a legal thing. Is this a case that all the work is done under the proverbial table, with no books or taxes paid? I don't judge, but in order to help this point needs to be clear. And even if you may not have a written contract, if you are providing a service and being paid, you have a contract in place, just that it's not written.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul He creates invoices for his services and he is paying his taxes (and he paid them in the previous 2 countries as well). He even has an accountant. I am unsure of the details about how this is possible, but there is no contract, he could never contact this company again if he wanted, and the company could stop paying and sending tasks anytime and my friend won't be able to reclaim those missing payments. At least this is what I've been told.

Comment: @freelance-friend So he is running a company, some sort of limited entity through which he contracts? If so, he screwed.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I guess you may call that a company, though it seems to be common enough that every freelancer in his industry does it. They still call themselves "freelancers", maybe this is why it is confusing to use that term in the OP.

Comment: @freelance-friend With the edit this is 100% out of scope for the Workplace.  I'm withdrawing my answer and voting to move.  This isn't a communication issue between co-workers this is very specifically a freelancing issue that would not impact anyone in any other type of work environment (with a contract this would be applicable to a larger subset of workers).

Comment: @Myles I guess you are right. Initially I thought it would be a better fit here due to the fact that the issue can be seen as an "injustice from people of power that makes changes unilaterally".

Comment: downvoter care to explain?

Comment: @freelance-friend downvoter does not have to...

Comment: @SolarMike sure but I invite them to explain :)

Comment: Sure this is not a standard workplace scenario but my friend still interacts daily with a team and complete tasks for a company for money. The issue presented is that the company did a change unilaterally which affects my friend and the others on the team equally. The resolution to this problem I believe it may be achieved through cooperation with the teammates considering that they are highly trained (and need specific training for this company) and have been working together for more than a year.

Comment: My answer would be: "Sure, I'll stop working on the low priority project,  just tell me which one is high priority (for the full salary)." Why is he still working on it?

Comment: @Chris the team (of freelancers) receive tasks and they self-organize. One can say that he doesn't want to work on a specific task, but somebody has to work on it at some point (thus taking a paycut in this case). This team has decided to self-organize in a way where everybody earns more or less the same (and they have very similar rates). This is the reason the change made by the company affects everybody as they behave more like a freelance-team rather than freelance-individuals.

Comment: @freelance-friend "...my friend still interacts daily with a team and complete tasks for a company for money." No your friend works for a company that has it's sole employee interacting daily with a team and the issue is that company completely messed up.  That is exactly why this is a poor fit here because it isn't about their interaction with co-workers it's that they lacked business sense when establishing a business relationship.

Answer (score 1):

> For now I advised him to contact the other freelancers to see if any of them has ever experienced this kind of paycut and how it was resolved in the end.

Sure, if they're silly enough to give him information, he might as well take it.

But apart from that he's an individual working under the table. Don't try group action, he has no leverage so it just puts him in the firing line. Watch and wait to see what the others do, if one wants to poke their head up then great. If not he should negotiate for himself. Nothing is not-negotiable, the only question is whether it will leave him unemployed during a global pandemic when he's more unlikely to get work.

Comment: Maybe you are right, though this company requires a specific training, which means that the company cannot easily find a replacement. I don't know exactly how the team is but per my understanding this is one of those teams that work well together, and have been delivering top notch quality for over a year. Everybody in the team was equally affected by what the company did, so I though that the solution to the problem might be achieved with teamwork given their history.

Comment: You're looking at it wrong, 3 taking a 40% cut, costs more than getting rid of 2 and paying the last one in full or getting rid of one and keeping 2 at less of a reduction. You need to analyse the risks against what you know. Being the ringleader is a quick and easy way of providing a target and negotiating power. When hiring under the table you don't keep a mini union leader.

Comment: ha, that's smart. On the other hand I understand that the pandemic is affecting everything but for now my friend and the others on the team have had more work than ever, this is why it seems like a sudden change wanting to get rid of a guy considering that they need rather the opposite... This is why I am a little puzzled of what the company is trying to achieve (apart from reducing costs).

Comment: In hard times you don't risk your revenue stream without concrete certainty that it will have a positive outcome.